# Writing collection to all worksheets with for each loop

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, foreach, collections

I've searched the site for quite a while now and found some solutions. However, I've not managed to implement it to my problem. I can make the program run as I wish, but I wanted to create it in a more correct manner (code-wise, to learn..). I got 60 worksheets, where the first is my main data sheet. The others are simply just different places to store different information.

I've got the following code, and I'm running it for all 60 worksheets.

```
Function ws61_function()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws61 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Worksheets(1)
Set ws61 = Worksheets(61)

Dim fRow As Long
Dim sRow As Integer
Dim col As Integer
Dim SDCol As Integer

sRow = 8
col = 2
SDCol = 3

With ws1
    fRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, SDCol).End(xlUp).Row
End With

Dim arr() As Variant
Dim coll As New Collection
Dim refol As Integer

refcol = 2

Dim wk As String
Dim ordrenummer As String
Dim ordrekontoret As String
Dim engineering As String
Dim kundeendring As String
Dim land As String
Dim prodordre_endring As String
Dim tolvtjuefire As String
Dim trettiseks As String
Dim desc As String


For i = sRow To fRow

wk = ws1.Cells(i, refcol).Value
ordrenummer = ws1.Cells(i, refcol + 1).Value
ordrekontoret = ws1.Cells(i, refcol + 2).Value
engineering = ws1.Cells(i, refcol + 3).Value
sales = ws1.Cells(i, recol + 4).Value
kundeendring = ws1.Cells(i, refcol + 5).Value
land = ws1.Cells(i, refcol + 6).Value
prodordre_endring = ws1.Cells(i, refcol + 7).Value
tolvtjuefire = ws1.Cells(i, refcol + 8).Value
trettiseks = ws1.Cells(i, refcol + 9).Value
desc = ws1.Cells(i, refcol + 10).Value

If land = ws61.Name Then
    coll.Add Array(wk, _
                    ordrenummer, _
                    ordrekontoret, _
                    engineering, _
                    sales, _
                    kundeendring, _
                    land, _
                    prodordre_endring, _
                    tolvtjuefire, _
                    trettiseks, _
                    desc)
End If
Next


   On Error GoTo gotcha



   ReDim arr(1 To coll.Count, 1 To 12)


For i = 1 To coll.Count
    arr(i, 1) = coll(i)(0)
    arr(i, 2) = coll(i)(1)
    arr(i, 3) = coll(i)(2)
    arr(i, 4) = coll(i)(3)
    arr(i, 5) = coll(i)(4)
    arr(i, 6) = coll(i)(5)
    arr(i, 7) = coll(i)(6)
    arr(i, 8) = coll(i)(7)
    arr(i, 9) = coll(i)(8)
    arr(i, 10) = coll(i)(9)
    arr(i, 11) = coll(i)(10)
Next

ws61.Range("B2").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr


gotcha:
    Debug.Print Err.Number

    If Err.Number = 9 Then
        MsgBox "Run-time error occured. Exiting..."
    End If


End Function
```

What I've now tried, is to do these 60 functions in one for each loop. I got the following code,  but I keep getting myself into a

> run-time error (9, subscript out of range):

```
Function ws_function_foreach()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim fRow As Long
Dim sRow As Integer
Dim col As Integer
Dim SDCol As Integer

Dim arr() As Variant
Dim coll As New Collection
Dim refol As Integer

Dim wk As String
Dim ordrenummer As String
Dim ordrekontoret As String
Dim engineering As String
Dim kundeendring As String
Dim land As String
Dim prodordre_endring As String
Dim tolvtjuefire As String
Dim trettiseks As String
Dim desc As String

Set ws1 = Worksheets(1)

sRow = 8
col = 2
SDCol = 3
refcol = 2

With ws1
    fRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, SDCol).End(xlUp).Row
End With


For i = sRow To fRow
    col1 = ws1.Cells(i, refcol).Value
    col2 = ws1.Cells(i, refcol + 1).Value
    col3 = ws1.Cells(i, refcol + 2).Value
    col4 = ws1.Cells(i, refcol + 3).Value
    col5 = ws1.Cells(i, recol + 4).Value
    col6 = ws1.Cells(i, refcol + 5).Value
    col7 = ws1.Cells(i, refcol + 6).Value
    col8 = ws1.Cells(i, refcol + 7).Value
    col9 = ws1.Cells(i, refcol + 8).Value
    col10 = ws1.Cells(i, refcol + 9).Value
    col11 = ws1.Cells(i, refcol + 10).Value
Next i

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If col7 = ws.Name Then
        coll.Add Array(col1, _
                col2, _
                col3, _
                col4, _
                col5, _
                col6, _
                col7, _
                col8, _
                col8, _
                col9, _
                col10)
       End If

On Error GoTo gotcha

ReDim arr(1 To coll.Count, 1 To 12)

For i = 1 To coll.Count
    arr(i, 1) = coll(i)(0)
    arr(i, 2) = coll(i)(1)
    arr(i, 3) = coll(i)(2)
    arr(i, 4) = coll(i)(3)
    arr(i, 5) = coll(i)(4)
    arr(i, 6) = coll(i)(5)
    arr(i, 7) = coll(i)(6)
    arr(i, 8) = coll(i)(7)
    arr(i, 9) = coll(i)(8)
    arr(i, 10) = coll(i)(9)
    arr(i, 11) = coll(i)(10)
Next

ws.Range("B2").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr

Next ws

gotcha:
    Debug.Print Err.Number

    If Err.Number = 9 Then
        MsgBox "Run-time error occured. Exiting..."
    End If

End Function
```

Any help is greatly appriciated! :-)

Thx

Comment: First remove that `on error` clause and see where the error is occurring.

Comment: Hi, thanks. The error occurs in the ReDim are part.

Comment: I suspect when your variable `coll` (collection object) is unset then it will prompt for an error.

Comment: What do you mean by unset? I’ve defined it as a value?

Comment: The variable `coll` gets set only if this condition `If col7 = ws.Name Then` is `True` otherwise it will not get set.

Comment: Yes, that’s intentional. I only want to add to collection if col7 = ws.Name. However, I need to do this for 60 different worksheets.

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest to move the rest of the associated code inside `IF...END IF` and test.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll try that. Found that I have two i integers as well, though it should’ve been two different integer variables..

Comment: I tried your suggestion @shrivallabha.redij, and code runs smoothly. It looks like all iterations works properly and array elements gets written over to collection. What still does not work though, is the resize to worksheet part. It does not write to ws..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202335/discussion-between-shrivallabha-redij-and-havard-kleven).

Comment: I've manage to do almost what I wanted now.. I got the array to write to all worksheets, however it writes the array in its whole - not only if the conditions are met. Any suggestions? Changed the llocation of the {IF..END IF} and replaced the integer {i} in the for-loop after {ReDim} to a j-looop.